# Combine asyncio.ensure_future and loop.run_until_complete in a single api call?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have written a async function which collects multiple text data and does data processsing in a batch. After that, it returns the output, like this:

```
import sys
import asyncio

Model_runner():
    '''
    The model runner combines all the input coming to it and combines in a batch of 10 or 1 sec, which ever duration is less. 
    After combining, it does processing and returns the output 
    '''


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
model_obj = ModelRunner(loop)
loop.create_task(model_obj.model_runner())


async def process_text(text):
        out_ = await model_obj.process_input(text)
        return out_
```

To get the output, I am running the following code:

```
task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(process_text(text1))
task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(process_text(text2))
task3 = asyncio.ensure_future(process_text(text3))
task4 = asyncio.ensure_future(process_text(text4))
async_tasks = [task1, task2, task3, task4]
out1, out2 ,out3 ,out4 = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*async_tasks))
```

Here, out1, out2, out3, and out4 are the output after processing the text data.

Here, I do not want to combine the task like [task1, task2, task3, task4] and then call the loop.run_until_complete to get the output. Instead, I am looking for a function like this:

```
out1 = func(text1)
out2 = func(text2) 
etc..
```

But, they should work in in non blocking way like asyncio.ensure_future. How can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want `func(text2)` to only start once `func(text1)` is complete, etc., or do you want them both to run at the same time?

Comment: @ArthurTacca I want both the functions to run at the same time, as I want to call them from threads that generate the text data. I do not want to create async_tasks. The Model_runner will handle if multiple inputs are coming at the same time. Basically, func(text) should work as a async api over the process_text(text) function.

Comment: @ArthurTacca  The text data is generated continuously over multiple threads and each thread should be able to call ```process_text(text)``` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious options:

- If you already have multiple threads, why bother with asyncio at all? Just make `process_text` a regular blocking function and call it from those threads.
- Conversely, if you're using asyncio, why use multiple threads at all? Make your top-level tasks async and run them all in one thread.

If you really must use multiple threads and async functions:

- Have a single thread running your asyncio loop and the worker threads you already mentioned, and use [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) in the threads to force the asyncs function to run in the async thread. If you want to get the result back to the thread you can use a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to send the result (or results) back.
- This final option is the worst one possible and almost certainly not what you want, but I mention it for completeness: start a separate asyncio event loop from each thread that needs it and use those to run your async functions in the worker threads directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I was working on the second method that you suggested, and not using any threads here. I am using loop.run_forever()
`

`
But, now I am getting memory leak. As my precessing is done in GPU, my memory is increasing at the operation is running. Can you suggest any methods to resolve?
### starting asyncio operation
`
    asyncio_list = []
    for i in range(cam_run):
        print("cam ", i, " initialised")
        asyncio_list.append(asyncio.ensure_future(process_text(text)))

    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()
`